# Function that returns parent directory absolute path

Tags: directories

```
    (parent-dir "/home/sk/parent/ab.el")
```

gives

```
    "/home/sk/parent"
```

then,

```
(parent-dir "/home/sk/parent")
```

gives

```
"/home/sk"
```

Any elisp function as `parent-dir` that gives basepath for both file path & dir path?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

`file-name-directory` does what you request.

However, `(file-name-directory "/home/sk/parent/")` (with a trailing slash) returns that same directory, not its parent.

This does what I'm guessing you *really* want:

```el
(file-name-directory (directory-file-name "/home/sk/parent/ab.el")) ; => "/home/sk/parent/"
(file-name-directory (directory-file-name "/home/sk/parent/")) ; => "/home/sk/"
(file-name-directory (directory-file-name "/home/sk/parent")) ; => "/home/sk/"
```

---

And library [Dired+](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/DiredPlus) uses this function:

```lisp
(defun diredp-parent-dir (file &optional relativep)
  "Return the parent directory of FILE, or nil if none.
Optional arg RELATIVEP non-nil means return a relative name, that is,
just the parent component."
  (let ((parent  (file-name-directory (directory-file-name (expand-file-name file))))
        relparent)
    (when relativep
      (setq relparent  (file-name-nondirectory (directory-file-name parent))))
    (and (not (equal parent file))  (or relparent  parent))))
```

Answer (score 0):

```el
(defun parent-directory (dir)
  (unless (equal "/" dir)
    (file-name-directory (directory-file-name dir))))
```

Taken from https://stackoverflow.com/a/14096693/5103881

Comment: Does this work on MS-Windows?